# Xpath and images in php

Tags: php, image, xpath

Trying to scrape images and data from a website using Xpath but keeps showing me an error.Could anybody help me out.

```
 <?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.hassconsult.co.ke/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22&Itemid=29');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query("//div[@id='ad']/table") as $table) {
  echo $xpath->query(".//img[@align='centre']", $table)->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";// should come in here don't know what to put 
  echo $xpath->query(".//span[@class='style8']", $table)->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";
  echo $xpath->query(".//div[@class='style10']/div", $table)->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";

  echo $xpath->query("//div[@align='justify']", $table)->item(0)->nodeValue. "\n";
}

?>
```

This is the outline as given buy firebug

```
 <td>
<div align="center" style="border:1px #007AC7 solid;width:199px;height:131px;">
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II">
<img width="199" height="131" border="0" style="border:1px #007AC7 solid;" alt="Photo" src="/images/markers/l_569.jpg">
</a>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: *img* doesn't have `nodeValue`, it has **attributes**

Comment: The site gave me permission so no worries there. so some assistance please. Still kinda stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the example you pointed to doesn't have any `IMG` tags with attribute `align='centre'` -- if you remove `[@align='centre']` you'll be able to use `getAttribute('src')` as Shikiryu indicates, e.g.

```
echo $xpath->query(".//img", $table)->item(0)->getAttribute('src'). "\n";
```

Comment: I'd even say, it should be `[@align='center']` and not **centre**

Comment: that's true, but it won't match the `IMG` tags of the proposed input

Comment: i have another question what if i want multiple images that are nested in a table like this                        div id="mainbody">
<table width="502" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" height="69">
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&photo_no=1">
<img width="50" height="45" border="0" style="border:1px #993300 solid;" alt="logo" src="/images/photos/p569_1.jpg">
</a>

Comment: to handle multiple images, keep in mind that `$xpath->query(".//img", $table)` is returning a DOMNodeList, so if you look at $list->length, you can then iterate over the `IMG` tags and `->get($i)` each one in turn.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment : attributes :

```
echo $xpath->query(".//img[@align='centre']", $table)->item(0)->getAttribute('src'). "\n";
```

Comment: I edited my question giving the html since there is no class for img i'm abit confused..//img[what should go here]",$table)->item(0)->getAttribute('src')."\n"